# How to optimize Shapely and Sklearn code?

Tags: python, distance, geopandas, nearest-neighbor, haversine

I am working with a dataset of 4.2 millions points and my codes is already taking a while to process, however below code is taking several hours to process **(the code was provided in other public question and basically it takes the nearest linestring to a point, finds the nearest point from that line string and calculus the distance)**

The codes actually does an awesome job, but takes too long for its purposes, How I can optimize or do the same thing in a shortest time?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric

EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES = 3440.1 #NAUTICAL MILES

panama = gpd.read_file("/Users/Danilo/Documents/Python/panama_coastline/panama_coastline.shp")

for c in range(b):
    #p = Point(-77.65325423107359,9.222038196656131)
    p=Point(data['longitude'][c],data['latitude'][c])

    def closest_line(point, linestrings):
        return np.argmin( [p.distance(linestring) for linestring in  panama.geometry] )
    
    closest_linestring = panama.geometry[ closest_line(p, panama.geometry) ]
    closest_linestring
    closest_point = nearest_points(p, closest_linestring)
           
    dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
    points_as_floats = [ np.array([p.x, p.y]) for p in closest_point ]
        
    haversine_distances = dist.pairwise(np.radians(points_as_floats), np.radians(points_as_floats) )
    haversine_distances *= EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES

    dtc1=haversine_distances[0][1]
    dtc.append(dtc1)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome :) Have you tried optimizing it yourself and run into problems doing so? Did you measure the performance of this method? Do you have a specific time/performance requirement for this method? Where exactly did you get this code from?

Comment: Don't place `def closest_line()` inside a loop. `dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')` is not changing, place it outside the loop.

Comment: Can you place data samples? When working with large points you want to calculate using trees.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Simplify to single calculation with BallTree

Imports

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
```

Read Panama

```
panama = gpd.read_file("panama_coastline/panama_coastline.shp")
```

Get all points, long,lat format:

```
def get_points_as_numpy(geom):
    work_list = []
    for g in geom:
        work_list.append( np.array(g.coords) )
        
    return np.concatenate(work_list)
        
all_coastline_points = get_points_as_numpy(panama.geometry)
```

Create Balltree

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

panama_radians =  np.radians(np.flip(all_coastline_points,axis=1))

tree = BallTree(panama_radians, leaf_size=12, metric='haversine')
```

Create 1M random points:

```
mean = [8.5,-80]
cov = [[1,0],[0,5]] # diagonal covariance, points lie on x or y-axis


random_gps = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,(10**6))
random_points = pd.DataFrame( {'lat' : random_gps[:,0], 'long' : random_gps[:,1]})
random_points.head()
```

Calculate closest coast point (<30 Seconds on my machine)

```
distances, index = tree.query( np.radians(random_gps), k=1)
```

Put results in DataFrame

```
EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES = 3440.1

random_points['distance_to_coast'] = distances * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES
random_points['closest_lat'] = all_coastline_points[index][:,0,1]
random_points['closest_long'] = all_coastline_points[index][:,0,0]
```

[image: img]